# What's the best way to handle API authentication for users (especially for mobile devices)

Tags: api, authentication, mobile, oauth

We're looking to create an API for our website. One of the major usages for the API (I suspect) will be to allow people to create mobile apps (for the iPhone and hopefully other devices).

What's the best way to handle API authentication for users. As a general rule, I don't like encouraging our users to hand their username/email/password details over to a 3rd party. However, is using oAuth acceptable/mature enough to work with for mobile devices? The only people using oAuth for mobile apps appear to have been Pownce, which seems to have had user issues and in any case is no longer around for me to see how they have dealt with the problem.

(Our user base is very untechnical, so I would expect <1% to have ever dealt with oAuth before)

The choice seems to be:

1. Ignore the issue with 3rd parties and passwords
2. Force developers to implement oAuth integration
3. Try something user unfriendly (such as using a secret key rather than their password)

Am I missing something?

Comment: maybe create a web based login that 3rd parties must display to the user.  the form prompts for username/password, and posts to your api server with a callback to the 3rd party's application including a response key.  the 3rd party would not have access to the user's username/password input in this way

Answer (score 0):

I dont think I completely understand your question, what do you mean by "handle API authentication for user" ? Do you want to make users authenticate themselves before using your API? Or something else?

One thought though, and this is true I think for any mobile platform. If you have an API that will work through a browser, then any mobile app, on first launch after download should be able to launch a browser (all mobile platforms allow this) and do any type of one time authentication.

Hope this helps, further clarifications on your question will help me give a better answer.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is: what's the best way to get users to authenticate themselves to our web application, when using an API. e.g. so an example would be, a third-party writes an iPhone app that uses our API. When a user uses the iPhone app, they need someone to connect the app with their account on our website via the API. I don't want our users to just hand their passwords and account details over to the third-party (who may store them insecurely, or harvest them etc). So what are the options? Do mobile developers mind using oAuth instead? Are there alternatives etc.

Comment: One option would be to create a library that third party uses to package in, into the app. This library connects to the website and authenticates the user. That way the third party doesnt need to be involved at all. This library can be in executable format (static lib maybe?). The third party never knows the details of it, they just use it. This mechanism is quite common in mobile field, music DRM companies like Groove provide it for DRM encryption to third parties.